# How to check string in a string array contains a seach text parse.com android

Tags: android, arrays, parse-platform, contains, startswith

I have an android project which uses parse.com as backend. I have an array column called keywords in Users table for example ["name","username"]. I used cloud code beforeSave method to achieve that. But I can't use this keywords array for searching because I can't find any contains or startsWith method for arrays. Is there any way to do that or any workaround?

Answer (score -1):

You can either use `equalTo` or `whereContainsAll` to find objects where the array key contains a specified value.

For example, if you want to find users that have the keywords *stackoverflow* and *android* in this field you could do it like this:

```
// Values to search for
ArrayList<String> keywordList = new ArrayList<String>();
keywordList.add("stackoverflow");
keywordList.add("android");

// Construct a query for users
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
query.whereContainsAll("keywordsField", keywordList);
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
  public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
        // The query was successful.
    } else {
        // Something went wrong.
    }
  }
});
```

The relevant documentation can be found [here](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide#queries-queries-on-array-values).

Comment: Thank you for the answer but this does not provide contains or startsWith methods functionality. User has to write the whole word. I want to find "stackoverflow" when user writes "stac"

Comment: It does offer `contains` for full strings. For substring search you're out of luck here and would probably have to implement this client side